# SQL Server materialized with ID column auto Increment

Tags: sql-server

I want to create a SQL Server table materialized view where I want to add an extra column named `ID` which is auto increment.

Is that possible?

Answer (score 2):

No, that's not possible. The restrictions on indexed views prevent this.

The ID would not be stable anyway. It would change in unexpected ways when the underlying data changes. The view is not a persistent table. It reflects what the view definition says at all times.

Use something else as the key of the indexed view. Usually, there is a suitable combination of columns from the underlying tables.

Comment: Can we generate uniq PK from few colums?

Comment: @blane Yes, that can be a very useful thing to do. Create a unique index on those columns.